# Unity 5 2D Flip Player

Tags: position, touch, 2d, unity-game-engine

I made player script with touch location and Flip code to flip player which direction is run I made like this  but just flip from 0. If is on x = -5 and I touch to go in x = 2 player doesn't flip but when is on x = 0 is flipped. Can someone tell me how to do this and I like to make with floor but my player move only on one floor in yAxis direction it save but when I remove yAxis it move all around I like to move like this game[Game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeRmY.png)

```
if (gameObject.transform.position.x > 0 && faceRight)
            {
                Flip();
            }
            else if (gameObject.transform.position.x < 0 && !faceRight)
            {
                Flip();
            }
```

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool flag = false;
    private Vector3 endPoint;
    public float duration;
    private float yAxis;
    private bool Run = false;
    private Animator anim;
    private bool faceRight = true;

    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        //save the y axis value of gameobject
        yAxis = gameObject.transform.position.y;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        //check if the screen is touched / clicked   
        if ((Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began) || (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)))
        {
            //declare a variable of RaycastHit struct
            RaycastHit hit;
            //Create a Ray on the tapped / clicked position
            Ray ray;
            //for unity editor
#if UNITY_EDITOR
            ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            //for touch device
#elif (UNITY_ANDROID || UNITY_IPHONE || UNITY_WP8)
   ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
#endif

            //Check if the ray hits any collider
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
            {
                //set a flag to indicate to move the gameobject
                flag = true;
                //save the click / tap position
                endPoint = hit.point;
                //as we do not want to change the y axis value based on touch position, reset it to original y axis value
                endPoint.y = yAxis;
                Debug.Log(endPoint);
            }

        }
        //check if the flag for movement is true and the current gameobject position is not same as the clicked / tapped position
        if (flag && !Mathf.Approximately(gameObject.transform.position.magnitude, endPoint.magnitude))
        { //&& !(V3Equal(transform.position, endPoint))){
          //move the gameobject to the desired position
            gameObject.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(gameObject.transform.position, endPoint, 1 / (duration * (Vector3.Distance(gameObject.transform.position, endPoint))));
            Run = true;
            anim.SetBool("Run", Run);

            if (gameObject.transform.position.x > 0 && !faceRight)
            {
                Flip();
            }
            else if (gameObject.transform.position.x < 0 && faceRight)
            {
                Flip();
            }
        }
        //set the movement indicator flag to false if the endPoint and current gameobject position are equal
        else if (flag && Mathf.Approximately(gameObject.transform.position.magnitude, endPoint.magnitude))
        {
            flag = false;
            Run = false;
            anim.SetBool("Run", Run);
            Debug.Log("I am here");
        }
    }

    void Flip()
    {
        faceRight = !faceRight;
        Vector3 theScale = transform.localScale;
        theScale.x *= -1;
        transform.localScale = theScale;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you figured it out how to do it?

Comment: No sir dont make this project anymore because i dont now how to do this. Thank you for your atention.

Answer (score 0):

Well my anwer will be diffrent from your code but if you want to flip character when you running left (i am assuming the default as right), you can simply check

if character's velocity > 0 then scale 1 and if character's velocity < 0 then scale -1

That will face the character to the rotation you go and this will be easy than the original code, but if you want to achieve something else please let me know so i can correct my answer on your needs :)

Comment: Thanks for you answer but rigibody2d doesnt work with this code can you tell simple way code to do this thanks

Comment: Actually you change the scale for the `Transform`, not `Rigidbody`

Comment: @Toni you dont need to use rigidbody, you can use the same method i said and instead of velocity you can take the current possition and if player position > current possition it means you are going right, because the game is 2D you can be sure about it :)

Answer (score 0):

Flipping the character seems to be a thing that `Animator` should handle. I saw that you're already using `Animator`, so you should make something like:

```
anim.SetInteger("direction", 1)
```

or even:

```
anim.SetFloat("position", transform.position.x)
```

and configure the animator to act accordingly, creating the animation states with the character facing left and right (with the gameObject's transform `scale.x` `1` and `-1` or `rotation.y` `0` and `180`) and the transitions to respond to the events you decided to watch.